# How do I change position in loop once the loop is completed?

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, position

```
finalList = []
list = []
c = 0
d = 0
for item in house_numbers:
    list.append(item)
    finalList.append(list)
    list = []
while population[c] != d:
    finalList[0].append(age[d])
    d += 1
```

I am appending 2 different lists to make a 2d list. house_numbers is a list that has the house numbers.

example:

```
Enter the next house number: 3
Enter the next house number: 4
[3, 4]
```

population is a list that corresponds to the amount of people in each house.

example:

```
Enter the amount of people in house 3: 2
Enter the amount of people in house 4: 1
[2, 1]
```

age is a list that has the ages for all the people.

example:

```
Enter the age of person 1 in house 3: 44
Enter the age of person 2 in house 3: 33
Enter the age of person 1 in house 4: 55
[44, 33, 55]
```

I want the `finalList` to look something like

```
[[house_numbers, age, age, age], 
 [house_numbers, age, age]]
```

I need `c` to stay the same for the duration of the while loop, then increase by one when the loop finishes. I can't just make another loop, because I need it to work for any number.

I tried looping the while loop with a for loop

Comment: How do `c` and `d` correspond to the questions you're asking?

Comment: Why don't you rearrange the questions so it asks for all the information about a house at one time, rather than asking for house numbers first, then populations, then ages?

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a built-in type name.

Comment: You are shadowing the python built-in `list` and your `for` loop doesn't make any sense. I see what you are trying to do with that. All you need is `finallist.append([item])`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a single loop that loops over the `house_numbers` and `population` lists together. Then use a nested loop that gets all the ages for that house.

```
final_list = []
for house, num_people in zip(house_numbers, population):
    row = [house]
    for p in range(1, num_people+1):
        age = int(input(f'Enter the age of person {p} in house {house}: '))
        row.append(age)
    final_list.append(row)
```